# How to fix longtable in right margin

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx

Hello I tried some solutions proposed in other similar questions but I didn't get any solution, my problem is that the longtable don't fix as I want.

```
 \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{lscape}
    \usepackage{pbox}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
    \small
 \begin{longtable}{p{3cm}p{3cm}p{5.5cm}}
 \hline \multicolumn{1}{l}{ \textbf{Clase:} Controller}  \\
 \hline \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Descripci\'{o}n de la clase:} Esta clase ser\'{a} la encargada de realizar la comunicaci\'{o}n con Condor, estableciendo una conexi\'{o}n con el servicio web. Contiene m\'{e}todos para el establecimiento de la conexi\'{o}n, creaci\'{o}n de trabajos u obtenci\'{o}n de informaci\'{o}n del cl\'{u}ster.}\\  
 \hline \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Datos} }\\ 
 \hline transacionTime & Integer & Esta variable es utilizada para determinar el tiempo de transacci\'{o}n utilizado en la llamada por pasos a las funciones del webservice Condor\\
 \hline  collectorUrl &  String & Almacena la direcci\'{o}n del servidor web de Condor y el puerto del collector.\\
 \hline  scheddUrl & String  & Almacena la direcci\'{o}n del servidor web de Condor y el puerto del schedd.\\
 \hline  collector & Client & Es el cliente para la comunicaci\'{o}n con el collector de Condor, con \'{e}l se realizar\'{a}n las llamadas a las funciones que ofrezca dicho collector.\\
 \hline  schedd & Client  & Es el cliente para la comunicaci\'{o}n con el schedd de Condor, con \'{e}l se realizar\'{a}n las llamadas a las funciones que ofrezca dicho schedd.\\
 \hline  \multicolumn{3}{l}{ \textbf{Clase: M\'{e}todos}}  \\
 \hline  constructor &  tipo\_metodo & descripci\'{o}n del m\'{e}todo\\
 \hline  createJob &  Job & Esta funci\'{o}n crea y devuelve un objeto de la clase Job configurado mediante los argumentos estabecidos en la funci\'{o}n.\\
 \hline  closeSpool &  void & Cierra el spool de un proceso, y todos los archivos contenidos dentro del mismo son eliminados.\\
 \hline  listSpool &  List & devuelve una lista con todos los archivos que se encuentran en el spool de un proceso dado.\\
 \hline  jobStatus &  Integer & Consulta a Condor el estado en el que se encuentra un proceso. En el manual de c\'{o}digo se especifica cuales son los estados en los que se puede encontrar un proceso.\\
 \hline  retrieveFiles &  void & Recupera y guarda e la carpeta asignada todos los archivos que se encuentran dentro del spool perteneciente a un proceso.\\
 \hline  getJob & ClassAd & Devuelve en forma de ClassAdd un proceso que se encuentra actualmente en el cl\'{u}ster.\\
 \hline  getPlatform &  String & Devuelve mediante un String la plataforma sobre la que se est\'{a} ejecutando Condor\\
 \hline  getVersion &  String & Devuelve en forma de String la versi\'{o}n de Condor.\\
 \hline  getMachines &  List & Devuelve una lista con todas las m\'{a}quinas que est\'{a}n conectadas actualmente en el cl\'{u}ster.\\
 \hline

 \caption[Ejemplo de especifiaci\'{o}n de clases]{Ejemplo de especifiaci\'{o}n de clases}
 \label{tab:especificacion_clase_controller}

 \end{longtable}
    \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

here the result:
[image]

Comment: I'm guessing your problem is the long second line, is that right?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change that second line of the table for

```
\hline \multicolumn{3}{p{11.5cm+2\tabcolsep}}{\textbf{Descripci\'{o}n de la clase:} Esta clase ser\'{a} la encargada de realizar la comunicaci\'{o}n con Condor, estableciendo una conexi\'{o}n con el servicio web. Contiene m\'{e}todos para el establecimiento de la conexi\'{o}n, creaci\'{o}n de trabajos u obtenci\'{o}n de informaci\'{o}n del cl\'{u}ster.}\\
```

Here, I am summing the width of your columns and the space between them so that the width of the total "column" equals the width of your original table

Comment: @tato469 In addition, add \usepackage{booktabs} in the preamble and change \hline to \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule.

Answer (score 3):

you need to fix the width of your second multicolumn, if you set it to `l` it will take the natural width of the text.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{lscape}
    \usepackage{pbox}

    \begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
    \small
 \begin{longtable}{p{3cm}p{3cm}p{7.3cm}}
 \hline \multicolumn{1}{l}{ \textbf{Clase:} Controller}  \\
 \hline \multicolumn{3}{p{\textwidth}}{\textbf{Descripci\'{o}n de la clase:} Esta clase ser\'{a} la encargada de realizar la comunicaci\'{o}n con Condor, estableciendo una conexi\'{o}n con el servicio web. Contiene m\'{e}todos para el establecimiento de la conexi\'{o}n, creaci\'{o}n de trabajos u obtenci\'{o}n de informaci\'{o}n del cl\'{u}ster.}\\
 \hline \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Datos} }\\
 \hline transacionTime & Integer & Esta variable es utilizada para determinar el tiempo de transacci\'{o}n utilizado en la llamada por pasos a las funciones del webservice Condor\\
 \hline  collectorUrl &  String & Almacena la direcci\'{o}n del servidor web de Condor y el puerto del collector.\\
 \hline  scheddUrl & String  & Almacena la direcci\'{o}n del servidor web de Condor y el puerto del schedd.\\
 \hline  collector & Client & Es el cliente para la comunicaci\'{o}n con el collector de Condor, con \'{e}l se realizar\'{a}n las llamadas a las funciones que ofrezca dicho collector.\\
 \hline  schedd & Client  & Es el cliente para la comunicaci\'{o}n con el schedd de Condor, con \'{e}l se realizar\'{a}n las llamadas a las funciones que ofrezca dicho schedd.\\
 \hline  \multicolumn{3}{l}{ \textbf{Clase: M\'{e}todos}}  \\
 \hline  constructor &  tipo\_metodo & descripci\'{o}n del m\'{e}todo\\
 \hline  createJob &  Job & Esta funci\'{o}n crea y devuelve un objeto de la clase Job configurado mediante los argumentos estabecidos en la funci\'{o}n.\\
 \hline  closeSpool &  void & Cierra el spool de un proceso, y todos los archivos contenidos dentro del mismo son eliminados.\\
 \hline  listSpool &  List & devuelve una lista con todos los archivos que se encuentran en el spool de un proceso dado.\\
 \hline  jobStatus &  Integer & Consulta a Condor el estado en el que se encuentra un proceso. En el manual de c\'{o}digo se especifica cuales son los estados en los que se puede encontrar un proceso.\\
 \hline  retrieveFiles &  void & Recupera y guarda e la carpeta asignada todos los archivos que se encuentran dentro del spool perteneciente a un proceso.\\
 \hline  getJob & ClassAd & Devuelve en forma de ClassAdd un proceso que se encuentra actualmente en el cl\'{u}ster.\\
 \hline  getPlatform &  String & Devuelve mediante un String la plataforma sobre la que se est\'{a} ejecutando Condor\\
 \hline  getVersion &  String & Devuelve en forma de String la versi\'{o}n de Condor.\\
 \hline  getMachines &  List & Devuelve una lista con todas las m\'{a}quinas que est\'{a}n conectadas actualmente en el cl\'{u}ster.\\
 \hline

 \caption[Ejemplo de especifiaci\'{o}n de clases]{Ejemplo de especifiaci\'{o}n de clases}
 \label{tab:especificacion_clase_controller}

 \end{longtable}
    \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

I changed the following two lines in your code:

```
\hline \multicolumn{3}{p{\textwidth}}{\textbf{Descripci\'{o}n % from l to p{\textwidth}
```

and

```
\begin{longtable}{p{3cm}p{3cm}p{7.3cm}}  % it was p{5.5cm}
```